# Redirecting user to original url after login page using onAuthenticationSuccess in spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I have an implementation of `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` that catches the request after user is successfully logged in. So when processing is finished inside a handler, I want to redirect a user to the page that he first desired to go, before he was redirected to the login page, and not to some hardcoded page. Is this possible?

This is how my handler implementation looks like:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    Util.setUserdata(userBean, authentication, request);
    
    proceed(request, response, authentication);
}
```

To explain the problem more clearly, a short example:

1. User wants to land to a page app/test/page.html
2. He gets redirected login page and logs in successfully
3. Handler method gets invoked and I do some logic after which I want to redirect him back to app/test/page.html, but I don't know how to access the URL he wanted to land on before redirection to login page.

Comment: Are you using spring security and if so what is your config?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I am, the part related to hander is `.successHandler(successHandler)` called on the `HttpSecurity` object. Other parts of the configuration is not related to this issue, I suppose. Just to be clear, this handler is working fine, I just don't know how to redirect user to the page that he first wanted to land on, before he was redirected to the login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Spring security's `ExceptionTranslationFilter` actually stores the request in session before redirecting to login.

  - [ExceptionTranslationFilter.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/ExceptionTranslationFilter.java#L210)
- And then it has `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` which is a `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` that retrieves and forwards to it.

  - [SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java#L77)
- You don't need to use that `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` directly if you have some customization. You can get the previous url directly from session like `session.getAttribute(""SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST")` as well and it has `url` and `method` etc so you can do the redirect yourself. You will have to cast it to `SavedRequest` before you can the url etc if you are going this route