# How to remove context path from redirect uri after oauth2 authorization

Tags: java, redirect, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

In my application, I have a context path `/api` and authorization with a path `/api/login/oauth2/code/keycloak` through a Keyloak.

After authorization, there is a redirect along the path `http://localhost:8080/api`. At the frontend, this causes errors, how can I remove the context path `/api` from the redirect after authorization?

Here are my settings. I tried to change the redirect path in the `oauth2Login`, the authorization endpoint, but this does not help. It only helped to put the URL after successful authorization in `defaultSuccessUrl`:

```java
.oauth2Login(login -> login.defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8080/)`
```

but it always sends to the same page, that is, it is not dynamic, it will not return back to the page from which they switched to authorization

```java
  http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeHttpRequests()
          .requestMatchers(matchers).permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
      .httpBasic().disable()
      .anonymous().disable()
      .oauth2Login()
          .and()
      .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler()))
      .oauth2ResourceServer()
          .jwt();
  return http.build();
```

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-id=myClientId
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.client-secret=myClientSecret
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.keycloak.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.user-name-attribute=preferred_username
```

If I have authorization from `http://localhost:8080/api`, then I want to return to `http://localhost:8080`, if `http://localhost:8080/somePage`, then to `http://localhost:8080/somePage`, but my authorization goes along the path `/api/oauth2/login` from default OAuth2 login settings, so OAuth2 returns to `/api`. And I need without it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to original URL after successful authentication in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71176804/redirect-to-original-url-after-successful-authentication-in-spring-security)

Comment: No, it's the other way around a decision on how to return to where you switched to authorization from. And if I have authorization from http://localhost:8080/api, then I want to return to http://localhost:8080. My authorization goes along the path /api/oauth2/login, so oauth2 returns to /api . And I need without him

Comment: *At the frontend, this causes errors, how can I remove the context path /api from the redirect after authorization?* Why is that a problem. Your application is under `/api`. There is nothing under `/`. You should not redirect to an URL outside your application.

Comment: Yes, but on the project before me, it happened that the frontend is located under /, and calls are sent under /api, any display is still under /, they definitely won’t change, especially now there is no front-dev on the project. Therefore, everything breaks down if you remove the context path or do not remove it, but continue to return it by /api.